# Loading XML file in PHP using physical path

Tags: php, xml

I am getting an error on trying to load a XML file using PHP when I  use the Physical path of the file. When the XML file is located in the same directory as code file I do not get a problem. 
Code is given below

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file(realpath('D:\XML\req.xml')) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
print_r($xml);
?>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Regards, 
Rahul

Comment: It's because your server software, probebly Apache, cannot reach outside the docroot unless you give it permission to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I can't offer advice on simplxml but the following, using DOMDocument, does work.

```
<?php
    $path=realpath('C:\wwwroot\files\xml\bbc_rss.xml');
    if( $path ){

        libxml_use_internal_errors( true );
        $dom=new DOMDocument;
        $dom->standalone=true;
        $dom->validateOnParse=false;
        $dom->strictErrorChecking=false;
        $dom->recover=true;
        $dom->formatOutput=false;
        $dom->load( $path );
        libxml_clear_errors();

        echo '<pre>', print_r( $dom->saveXML() ,true ),'</pre>';
        $dom=null;

    } else {
        echo 'unable to find the xml file.';    
    }
?>
```

When I tried with a bad xml ( ie: one that is poorly formed or considered invalid for some reason ) file nothing was displayed but with xml files I know to be ok it was fine. If you don't wish to use the DOMDocument method then might I suggest trying with a known xml file from the interwebs as a test?

Comment: The problem is simply that he's trying to access a file outside his docroot. Unless you give the apache service access to that folder, it just isn't going to work. No matter what kind of code you try :)

Comment: not quite true, at least not as far as I'm concerned - this works on my system no matter which folder I try to access. To be fair, it appears the path above is in my doc root but works equally well from another dir.

Comment: @RamRaider I think your answer should emphasize the *bad xml* file more, because people might easily missed that. I read it the second time to understand what you mean. (maybe just because not my native language, haha).

Comment: The webserver is IIS 7 . I tried the code above but that did not work. I am able to open the XML file from ASP code but get the error in PHP. Including the actual xml file below

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note>